# Manjaro, KDE, auto start application, skip desktop to taskbar

Tags: autostart

Is there a way to get an application that auto starts when I boot up to skip the desktop (skip the task manager as well) and go strait to the taskbar?

For example, I have Discord, which starts up when I boot and login. It always starts in my task manager and the desktop and I close it to get it back to my taskbar.